# android sqlite database error no such table

Tags: android, sqlite

i am having errors accessing the database through an android app. i am getting

> 11-30 21:31:17.452: E/SQLiteLog(17817): (1) no such table: draws
>
> 11-30 21:31:17.452: E/DataAdapter(17817): getTestData >>android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: draws (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT drawnumb, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6 FROM draws WHERE drawnumb = 1221

not sure what the problem is. if someone could light up the problem for me.
here are chunks of my code i believe are useful. if someone asks for more code please let me know.

any help is appreciated.

here is the the databaseHandler

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.Cursor;

public class databaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "drawManager",
    TABLE_DRAWS = "draws",
    KEY_DRAWNUMB = "drawnumb",
    KEY_B1 = "b1",
    KEY_B2 = "b2",
    KEY_B3 = "b3",
    KEY_B4 = "b4",
    KEY_B5 = "b5",
    KEY_B6 = "b6",
    KEY_B7 = "b7",
    KEY_WINNERS = "winners";

public databaseHandler (Context context){
    super (context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" + TABLE_DRAWS + "(" + KEY_DRAWNUMB + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+ KEY_B1 + " INTEGER," + KEY_B2 + " INTEGER,"+
            KEY_B3 + " INTEGER," + KEY_B4 + " INTEGER,"+KEY_B5 + " INTEGER," + KEY_B6 + " INTEGER,"+KEY_B7 + " INTEGER," + KEY_WINNERS + " INTEGER)");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

public Draw getDraw(int drawnum){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_DRAWS,  new String[] {KEY_DRAWNUMB, KEY_B1, KEY_B2, KEY_B3, KEY_B4,
            KEY_B5, KEY_B6, KEY_B7, KEY_WINNERS}, KEY_DRAWNUMB + "=?", new String []{String.valueOf(drawnum)} , null, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null)
    cursor.moveToFirst();

Draw draw = new Draw(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)),
        Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(5)),
        Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(6)),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(7)),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(8)));
db.close();
cursor.close();
return draw;
}
}
```

here is the fragment from the databaseHelper, where i am referencing the database test2.sqlite

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat   window
//destination path (location) of our database on device
private static String DB_PATH = ""; 
private static String DB_NAME ="test2.sqlite";// Database name
private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase; 
private final Context mContext;
```

this is where i am using the database to access a draw in the database and i am sure it exists

```
//database test
    buttonone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DataAdapter mDbHelper = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext());         
            mDbHelper.createDatabase();       
            mDbHelper.open(); 
             String results="";
            Cursor testdata = mDbHelper.getTestData(); 
            try {
                //for (int i=1;1<7;i++){
                    results = testdata.getString(1);//testdata.getColumnIndex("b"+ Integer.toString(i)));
                    results += " "+ testdata.getString(2);
                    results += " "+ testdata.getString(3);
                    results += " "+ testdata.getString(4);
                    results += " "+ testdata.getString(5);
                    results += " "+ testdata.getString(6);
                    
            }
                //results = testdata.getString(testdata.getColumnIndex("drawnumb"));
            //}
        catch (Exception ex) {
                results = "not working";
            }
            
            //String name = Utility.GetColumnValue(testdata, "Name");
            //String email = Utility.GetColumnValue(testdata, "Email");
            
            //Utility.ShowMessageBox(this, "Name: "+ name + " and Email: "+ email);
            mDbHelper.close();
            //res = getRandomNumbers(numbers);
            lottery.setText("Your numbers: " + results);
        }
    });
```

this should return the draw number 1221 as seen in the method found in my dataAdapter class

```
public Cursor getTestData()
 {
     try
     {
         String sql ="SELECT drawnumb, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6 FROM draws WHERE drawnumb = 1221";

         Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
         if (mCur!=null)
         {
            mCur.moveToNext();
         }
         return mCur;
     }
     catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
     {
         Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
         throw mSQLException;
     }
 }
```

Comment: 1) NEVER do sql queries in activities! That is so bad!  2 ) uninstall the app, and install it again, will it work ?

Comment: i tried that it didnt work.
note that i have not changed the database classes, i only changed the database using SQLite manager in firefox.
should that be a problem? the database has the same name.

Comment: `i only changed the database using SQLite manager in firefox` Then you must put your db in the **assets** folder and copy it in code to the **/data/data/...** path. You shouldn't then re-create the table.

Comment: i had the database in assets all that time. can you just give more info about that /data/data thing? i suppose that should be in the DatabseHelper right?

Comment: never mind mate, i have found what you mean in a book. i will read it and do it. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is why your table is not created:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" + TABLE_DRAWS + ...
```

You forgot to insert a space after the word `EXISTS`.
This is what you get without space: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTSdraws`.

So it works:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_DRAWS + ...
```

Comment: i have tried adding a space after exists the error is still the same.
and in other threads some said i should not add a space after EXISTS. please clear this one out, thanks

Comment: `in other threads some said i should not add a space after EXISTS.` I guess you are **joking**. This is what you get without space: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTSdraws`: how **do you think it can work?**